# Error in as.POSIXct.numeric() origin must be supplied

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct, facebook-prophet

`Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(ds, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "GMT") : 'origin' must be supplied`

This is the error I am getting while passing an array

```
arr <- c('2022-09-27','1','2022-09-28','2','2022-09-29','3','2022-09-30','2')
```

to function in R that calls prophet library method.

```
    ptmForecastTest <- function(nrows, ncols, prophetUncertaintyInterval, values, periods, freq){
    value_mat <- matrix(values, nrow=4, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
    df <- as.data.frame(value_mat)
    colnames(df) <- c('ds', 'y')
    model <- prophet(df, 0.8, growth='linear')
    return(df)
    }
```

The code breaks at `model <- prophet(df, 0.8, growth='linear')`. It is not able to accept the Dataframe.

```
    values <- c("2022-09-06 23:45:50",1,"2022-09-07 23:45:50",2,"2022-09-08 23:45:50",3,"2022-09-09   23:45:60",2) 
    val_mat <- matrix(values,4,2,byrow=TRUE) 
    df <- as.data.frame(val_mat) 
    colnames(df) <- c('ds','y') 
    as.POSIXct(df['ds'], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I tried this, but got error "Error in as.POSIXct.default(df["ds"], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") : do not know how to convert 'df["ds"]' to class “POSIXct”

So far I tried lubridate package methods, but nothing has worked and I am not able to understand how to resolve this. I have been working at it since 2 days. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you need `df$ds <- as.POSIXct(df$ds)` as `df['ds']` is still a data.frame with a single column, where as `df$ds` is a vector

Comment: I tried `df$ds <- as.POSIXct(df$ds);m <- prophet(df, growth = 'linear', changepoint.range = 0.8);future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 365)` is working without an error

Comment: Also `as.POSIXct(df[['ds']], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df$ds <- as.POSIXct(df$ds)
m <- prophet(df, growth = 'linear', changepoint.range = 0.8)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 365)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It is working now. is changepoint.range same as uncertainty interval?

Comment: @anisha I chose the named argument as there are lots of argument and placing 0.8 as second argument is not identifying which one you are passing.  The second argument is growth, followed by changepoints, ...  So you may need to specify the argument name or else it can assume by position

Comment: also, @akrun is it possible to pass 2D array from java to R, currently I am passing 1D array with dates and integers.

Comment: @anisha is that your original question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76127021/assigning-a-2d-string-array-from-java-to-r-through-rserve @akrun

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76215059/reason-for-error-in-catconditionmessagec-file-stderr-sep-ignori

Comment: do you know anything about  below issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76215059/reason-for-error-in-catconditionmessagec-file-stderr-sep-ignori