# Assigning a 2D String array from Java to R through Rserve

Tags: java, r, dataframe, rserve

Currently I am flattening a 2D array to 1D array and sending it to R function, but is there a way to send dataframe or 2D array directly to R. 2D array is a string array.
String[] str= {"2022-09-06 23:45:50","1","2022-09-07 23:45:60","2","2022-09-08 23:45:50", "3", "2022-09-09 23:45:60", "4"};
connection.assign("values",str);
This is the code where is assign 1D array to a variable. But how do I send 2D array with date and count as columns and number of rows is 4.